# How to copy one line from one attribute to another attribute in DOORs

Tags: ibm-doors

I'm trying to copy a line from DOORS one attribute and write that line into another attribute in DOORS.

Comment: Hello Dhruti,
is this a question about DXL or the DOORS GUI?
What do you mean by "line"?
Do I guess correctly that you have a multiline (text) attribute of an object which has e.g. 3 lines and you want to get the 2nd line from the attribute and make this line the 2nd line of a corresponding text attribute in the same object? 
Please give more details about your task.

Comment: Hello Mike,The question is about DXL script. I need a DXL script through which i can perform this task. For example: one attribute has test case written with 5 lines and i want to copy last line of that test case and paste it into another attribute.

Answer (score 0):

more or less straight from the DXL manual

```
Object o = current // might be set in a loop

Regexp line = regexp2 ".*"
string sTextValue = o."Object Text"""

string sLastLine = ""
while (!null sTextValue && line sTextValue) {
    sLastLine = sTextValue[match 0]
    sTextValue = sTextValue [end 0 + 2:]
}
print "->" sLastLine "<-\n"
o."Other Attribute" = sLastLine
```